# Fraction converted to PI

Tags: trigonometry

I've found this example:

$$ 7\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}(x + 1.25)\right) - 3 = 7\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}x + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - 3 $$

how could this $$(x + 1.25) $$ be converted to $$ x + \frac{\pi}{2} $$

? any hints please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You distribute the $\frac{2\pi}{5}$. Note that $\frac{2\pi}{5}1.25=\frac{2\pi}{5}\frac{5}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{2\pi}{5}(x+1.25)=\frac{2\pi}{5}x+\frac{2\pi}{5}\times 1.25$$
and that 
$$\frac{2\pi}{5}\times 1.25=\frac{2\pi}{5}\times\frac 54=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$